# SQL WHERE CHARINDEX

Tags: sql

My column ServicetTypeIDs contains the following data. I use the below where clause to search for values, lets say if my paramter @ServiceTypes = 1,9   it would only return me records when both 1,9 are present. I want to return records which contain either 1, 9 or records which have 1,9 itself. my where clause is not correct. please help

```
column
1
NULL
9
1
4,7
1,9

 WHERE
( @ServiceTypes is null or       
   charindex(','+SEP.ServiceTypeIDs+',',      
   ','+@ServiceTypes+',') > 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need for '1,9' select ('1','9','1,9') here is a short condition

```
where (@ServiceTypes is null) or (','+@ServiceTypes+',' like '%,'+ServiceTypeIds+',%')
```

But for '4,9' it selects only ('9'). If you want to get ('4,7','1,9','9') for this mask here is the condition

```
where (@ServiceTypes is null) 
      or 
      (','+ServiceTypeIds+',' like ',%'+SUBSTRING(@ServiceTypes,1,charindex(',',@ServiceTypes)-1)+',%')
      or
      (','+ServiceTypeIds+',' like ',%'+SUBSTRING(@ServiceTypes,charindex(',',@ServiceTypes)+1,1000)+',%')
```